# Is there a way to prevent autoformatter in VSC to change certain line/piece of code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autoformatting

I write some python scripts, and for the most of the time, I am totally OK with how autoformatter works. But sometimes I want to preserve a vertical consistency or split code into lines logically.

```
# autoformatter removes all leading spaces here
array = numpy.array([[
        [       0,     1589, 25825225,     1589,        0],
        [    1589, 26265625, 26265625, 26265625,     1589],
        [25825225, 26265625, 26265625, 26265625, 25825225],
        [    1589, 26265625, 26265625, 26265625,     1589],
        [       0,     1589, 25825225,     1589,        0],
]])
# autoformatter splits line at '-' sign in the first brackets
links[point.degree - 1].append([
    neighbor.index for neighbor in point.neighbors
])
```

Is there a way to tell autoformatter (I use default Python package for VSC) to ignore these lines (similar to `# pylint: disable=C0123` magic comment)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Python extension supports two formatters: autopep8 (default) and yapf. You can switch to yapf with the following configuration:

```
"python.formatting.provider": "yapf"
```

Yapf supports excluding regions from formatting via comments:

```
# yapf: disable
links[point.degree - 1].append([
   neighbor.index for neighbor in point.neighbors
])
# yapf: enable
```

I haven't found a similar feature for autopep8 (although you can disable [specific fixes](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8#features) globally with `--ignore`).